# Can you turn a Simulation into Keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes, fluid-simulation

Basically, if I have a fluid sim in one blend file, can I somehow turn it into keyframes to form an animation or an action and export it as an animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can export fluid sim in alembic format (File -> Export -> Alembic) and import to different application with alembic support. It work similar than create shape key for every frame, but it do it smarter way.

Comment: Blender keeps crashing everytime I try to export it using Alembic, but it still creates a file, but it seem to be corrupt, since nothing can open it. I'm using Blender 2.79 with the suppose Alembic improvement.

Comment: Oh nvm. I forgot to enable "Export Animated Mesh" on the inflow object. This seems to have stopped the crashing and I was able to export and open it. Thanks for the help!